# Подключение необходимых файлов проекта PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Экосистема: PHP 7.1, самописный проект, я основной разработчик, программист С/С++

Есть проект, имеющий банальную структуру:

- index.php (+mod_rewrite на него всех URL)
- /classes (куча файликов в папках и подпапках с описанием функций и классов)

Проект работает, все в порядке. Однако есть проблема - количество файлов растет. Я подключаю каждый новый файл через `require_once(...)` и их уже накопилось под сотню. Меня это не беспокоило

На днях встала задача интегрировать в мой проект разработки прошлых лет, который оформлены в виде иерархии классов, коих порядка 50+, каждый класс в своем файлике, в своем namespace, разделены по подпапкам, все очень логично и понятно

Я в лоб сделал `find . -name "*.php"` и прописал все в `requre_once()`, как обычно делал. Проверил, начали сыпаться трейсы PHP по поводу того, что какому-то классу нужен другой класс, от которого этот наследуется. Путем магических перестановок порядка подключения я добился того, что все заработало

Но я считаю такой подход не научным, не красивым

Вопрос:

1. Как в PHP принято решать проблемы зависимостей между классами и порядком подключения файлов?
2. Как реализуется в PHP это подключение? Желательно именно нативный вариант, а не вариант определенного фреймворка

Интересует два момента: быстродействие подключения/выполнения кода и удобство/безопасность реализации

Заранее оговорюсь - пожалуйста, не надо ссылаться на реализации этого механизма в популярных фреймворках. Я уверен, что они великолепны и замечательны, но интересует именно ванильный голый PHP 7 со стандартными библиотеками, подключаемыми через .so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте автозагрузку классов: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php
Вот пример:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Т.е. вы регистрируете функцию которая будет загружать ваши файлы с классами. В данном примере при выполнении new MyClass1() будет автоматически выполнен include MyClass1.php. Аналогично для MyClass2() будет include MyClass2.php

Comment: То есть нужно зарегистрировать некую функцию, которой будет передано имя класса, а в ней уже реализовать поиск необходимого файла где угодно и как угодно? Например можно составить массив из значений `classname => filename` или вроде того

Comment: Да, вы всё правильно поняли. Вот примеры работы с автозагрузкой: https://codengineering.ru/post/28

Comment: О, супер, зря вопрос задавал, надо было еще 5 минут посидеть в гугле ) Спасибо

Comment: @Diver, дополните вопрос примерами кода, пожалуйста) К сожалению сообщение, содержащее лишь ссылку не может считаться ответом по правилам сайта(